# EF code first modular design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, database-migration

Using ef4 code first you can create and compile classes and dbcontext. What happens when you want to add some classes/tables and relationships in an already compiled dll of a model set?

So far the solutions I have come up with are using "partial" classes, that would be complimented later on, and the second one is writing a whole new dbcontext that includes the first one in some way or extending it, but this would mean additional db connection per module (per db context). Any ideas about this? What's the best practice ? Also I need to be able to work with migrations.

More explicitly, a possible scenario is as follows:

A) You create a .dll with some dbContextBase class and tables(classes) inside that.

B) You create other .dlls that depend/extend dbContextBase in their own way*

C) You refference said .dlls in a project and extend them.

So basically you can have a core dbContext, then add a menu module to it, then you add a blog module to it (but it can be seen by the Menu module in order to create latest blog posts menus etc). On top of that, if you want a specific one-time feature for blog you can quickly integrate that, but also keep your blog module updateable.

As I beggin to see it the best way to do that is Nuget packages with the source code for the models (and the like) per module, instead of compiled dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no answer that focuses on the problem the way I put it, I am posting an answer with what seems to be the best workaround at this moment.

For full support of migrations, even custom migrations, and full support in general for code-first design, the best method is to import the source codes and compile directly.

We are using a local nuget feed in order to be able to sync multiple sub-modules freely and swiftly. This also leads to a good update experience since the migrations can easily be created or imported/integrated when needed

Answer (score 5):

You can build some infrastructure in your core assemblies which will discover entities in your modules and register them to single context. Each entity must have class derived from `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` (or `ComplexTypeConfiguration<>` for complex types) which will describe the mapping.

Once you have mapping classes you can either use some module interface to collect all of them for every module or use reflection to browse assemblies and create instances of mapping classes. These classes can be either use in by `DbModelBuilder` directly (either in `OnModelCreating` or directly).

> Also I need to be able to work with migrations.

I'm not sure if migrations are ready for this because it has some preconditions:

- All shared tables must be handled by the core assemblies - its own `DbMigration` derived class (or classes for new versions)
- Every module must handle its own tables - its own `DbMigration` derived class (or classes for new versions)
- Modules mustn't alter shared tables
- Modules mustn't alter or access tables of other modules

It means that you have special migration set for core and one migration set for every module. Every migration set is defined in separate assembly - this can be potential problem. I didn't try it myself so I don't know if EF migrations can handle this - I especially target scenarios where you really want modular systems where modules can be added or removed over time so you need both installation (`Up` method) and uninstallation (`Down` method).

The problem with migrations is that you cannot for those must and mustn't so if you develop the platform where people can add custom modules you never know if they don't break your core.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, great insight! I don't have any experience in this type of design so I will have to study your reply extensively. One clarification though, as there won't be any external developers for the moment, and I don't mind modules being able to access other modules , does this make for an easier solution that encompasses migrations?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your initial question correctly - what exactly do you mean by module? Is it just a library in your code where all libraries are always compiled and shipped together or is it some addition to existing product which can be added on removed without changing or recompiling the application?

Comment: I didnt explain it properly.  Yes the libraries will be compiled and shipped.  I have a core that is developed continously but it has modifications per client sometimes.  I want to create local nuget packages with the most current version of each feature so as to update easily and merge the changes seamlessly,  but preserve database versioning too! In the meantime I'm beggining to like your architecture very much! Would make remote deployment of features possible..

Comment: Using multiple DbContexts on the same database appears to occasionally confuse the migration class generator resulting scripts that try dropping the other's tables.  You can update the output to be correct and it appears to work. For some reason Add-Migration compares the database with the context instead of the context with the latest hash of the context, I guess there's not enough information stored in the previous migration.  Unless you have more luck I'd recommend separate databases per module.

Answer (score 1):

What about this scenario: one DbContext with some entities, on OnModelCreating, looks up additional classes on external assemblies which inherit from base classes on the assembly where this DbContext lives. I want to be able to update the already created database according to these classes, assuming they don't change base tables, only possibly add new ones. Is this possible? So far, from my experiences, using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, it merely ignores the new entities, that is, does not generate any new tables.

Comment: This is the general idea I am proposing in the question but is a different implementation that I haven't tried. And from what you are saying it doesn't work! Still in search for a solution different to just importing the source code...

Comment: @Mihalis: Yes, so far, no luck... If you find something, will you please post it here? I will do the same! Thanks!

Comment: @Mihalis: By the way, since I'm discovering entities automatically, I had to write this extension method: 
  public static void Entity(this DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type entityType)
  {
   typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
  }

Comment: The way we are doing it is by directly importing the source - even inheriting from the base class we have found that has enough problems not to be worth the trouble. I like your approach, and we will try to investigate on it though!

Comment: @Mihalis: nice! If you want, you can reach me at rjperes at hotmail.

Comment: Related blog post http://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/